# Jquery, hide div, replace div, show new div?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

This is my ajax success handler

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#contact'+finalForm[0].value).hide("drop", {direction: 'up'}, 1000,
  function(){
    $('#contact'+finalForm[0].value).replaceWith(data).show("drop", {direction: 'up'}, 1000,
    function(){
      $(document).trigger('close.facebox');
    });
  });
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is

Hide the Div
When the div is hidden
  Replace Contents with ajax response (response has the same id)
  When the content is replace
    Show the new content
    When the content is visible
      close facebox

However the actual process seems to happen as

Hide the div
When the div is hidden
Remove the div
close facebox

How can I fix this?

The response contains the expected html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error:

```
$('#contact'+finalForm[0].value).replaceWith(data)
```

instead of this use:

```
$('#contact'+finalForm[0].value).empty().append(data).show(....);
```